# Why is the $L^{\infty}$ norm controlled by the integration of Fourier transformation?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $u\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$, how to show:

$$||u||_{L^{\infty}}\leq \int |\hat u(x)|dx$$

Here $\hat u$ is the Fourier transformation of $u$.

I remembered this inequality was pretty simple but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: Apply inversion formula. (If RHS is $\infty$ there is nothing to prove).

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, thanks!